# empty session value when moving one page to other

Tags: php, mysql, session

Im having a problem of accessing the session variable value.

im creating a login page and this were i set the values of my session variables.

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$result=mysql_query("select * from myuser where id='".$id ."' and password='".$password."'");    
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $_SESSION['SESS_ID'] = $user['id'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_UNAME'] = $user['username'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_PASS'] = $user['password'];
    header("location:home.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

home.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_ID'])) == ''){
    header("location:index.php");
    exit();
}
?>

<html>
<body>
    <p>Login Successful</p>
<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_ID'] ; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

the problem here is i have no value in $_SESSION['SESS_ID']..so how do i get or access the value of this session variable in my home.php?

Edit: my query for the SQL is

> select * from myuser where id='".$id ."' and password='".$password."'

Comment: The reason why  `$_SESSION['SESS_ID']` isn't being set is pretty obvious - `mysql_num_rows($result) > 0` isn't true as you expected, to its block gets never executed

Comment: then what should i do David??

Comment: Show your query, first, instead of `<!--query written here -->`

Comment: and whether you're using the same API to connect with. You need a `while` loop also.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: "select * from myuser where id='".$id ."' and password='".$password."'";

Comment: David i show the query

Answer (score 1):

Some points about why you have this issue:

- the values you populate the `$_SESSION` array with come directly from the database, but you have no database SQL query - instead you have

> "!--query written here --"

If you can replace this placeholder with a query that returns your `id`, `username` and `password` values then your code should execute as expected.

I'm not certain if your syntax is wrong as such, but it is not the shape I would ever lay it out, my own shape would be:

```
   $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    while ($outputrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
       // In here $outputrow is an array of ONE row of your database, so
       // $outputRow['id'] = the id from one row. ordered by the ORDER BY in your SQL query. 
    }
```

- Add a `mysqli_error($connection)` clause to your SQL query to detect errors. such as :

Here:

```
  $result=mysqli_query($connection, "<!--query written here -->") or die("error :".mysqli_error($connection));
```

- As I have used across these examples, please, please STOP using MySQL and use at least MySQLi or even PDO. There are a host of improvements and bug fixes and lots of info on this transition on SO.
- Also, never, ever compare passwords as strings, passwords saved to a database should *as a minimum* be saved as hashes with PHP function `password_hash()`. Never have the line `if($_POST['pwd'] == $row['pwd']){`.
- Finally, as rightly mentioned by Fred-ii- in comments, add error logging and checking into your script so that you know what's going on:

Such as:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Add these to the very top of your PHP page and they will display your errors and warnings to you so you can see what is and is not working.

## EDIT:

From your edit there are two biq questions, your statement is that:

> "select * from myuser where id='".$id ."' and password='".$password."'

so where does the value `$id` and `$password` come from? is the `<?php` at the top of the page, if so, these variables will always be empty, you need to apply a value to these variables.

Comment: will i replace if loop with while?

Comment: yes, use the template structural format I have in my answer.

Comment: after the using while loop my page is not opening its only loading

Comment: you need to make changes 1 step at a time, if you copy/pasted my while loop then you'll need to make sure your page version is using MySQL not MySQLi

Comment: yup i m using right version mysql not mysqli and no error shown because page is only loading on server and if i use if loop then page opens immediately but empty session value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90929/discussion-between-amy-and-martin).